# How can I define a loop in a command?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am writing a code for ABAQUS software by python and I need to write below code  in a section of my code.

```
a1.InstanceFromBooleanMerge(name='agg', instances=(a1.instances['Part-1-1'], 
   a1.instances['Part-2-1'], ), keepIntersections=ON, 
   originalInstances=DELETE, domain=GEOMETRY)
```

In aforementioned code, The number of Part will be varied and I do not know how many part I have before running the code.

So,for example if I have 3 Parts, how can I adjust my code? in this case, code has to be same as followings;

```
a1.InstanceFromBooleanMerge(name='agg', instances=(a1.instances['Part-1-1'], 
    a1.instances['Part-2-1'], a1.instances['Part-3-1'],),                   
    keepIntersections=ON, originalInstances=DELETE, domain=GEOMETRY)
```

As you can see, this is a command and I do not know how I have to define something such `For` loop in a command???

Comment: What determines the number of parts? Which part of the code? Do you mean all the keys in `a1.instances` dictionary? If the order is not important you can do--> `instances=tuple(a1.instances.values())`

Comment: You could make a `tuple` variable of the instances outside of `InstanceFromBooleanMerge`, and then pass that variable in as the `instances` argument

Comment: @MYGz It is determined by calculating the length of a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension to build up the list "within" the method call:

```
a1.InstanceFromBooleanMerge(
    name='agg', 
    instances=tuple([a1.instances["Part-%s-1" % i] for i in range(1,4)]),                   
    keepIntersections=ON,
    originalInstances=DELETE,
    domain=GEOMETRY)
```

where 4 is the length of the matrix you get plus 1, e.g. `range(1, len(matrix)+1)`

Another way would be to build up the tuple outside the method call:

```
instances = tuple([a1.instances["Part-%s-1" % i] for i in range(1,4)])
a1.InstanceFromBooleanMerge(
    name='agg', 
    instances=instances,
    keepIntersections=ON,
    originalInstances=DELETE,
    domain=GEOMETRY)
```

Comment: No Philip. It's `a1.instances['Part-i-1']`

Comment: @MYGz where do you see that? above in the question it says e.g. `a1.instances['Part-3-1']`

Comment: Those are the keys of dictionary.

Comment: ah I see, I thought you were referring to the building of the key. I fixed this part, thanks for the hint

Comment: Still not right. Now you get `a1.instances[multiple-keys]`

Comment: yeah, I screwed up the brackets. Now it should be correct, thanks for pointing out

Comment: But I wouldn't put an operation like that inside a function call. I would also use string formatting. Although I guess OP asked about putting a loop _inside_ the command.

Comment: I am not much familiar with python, but when I am running my code contains this section, ABAQUS jump out and I do not know why.

Comment: @user44: can you post the code you have made from my example into your question? (I'm especially interested in the `len(matrix)` part, there you need to reference the right var)

Comment: @Jakub: fixed the string formatting, you're right it's nicer this way. Also spelled out how one would build up the tuple outside the function call

Comment: @hansaplast For beginning, I did it for a special case and I consider the `len(matrix)` be equal to 2. it means loop will be in range 1 and 3.

Comment: @user44: did the code you posted in your question work in ABAQUS?